# How to left align the section title in latex?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

I am using the `\documentclass{ctexart}`, and this document class centers the section title by default. How could I left align the section title?

Answer (score 8):

Here are two options:

1. Add `\raggedright` to all `\section`s globally:

   ```
   \documentclass{ctexart}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \makeatletter
   \g@addto@macro{\CTEX@section@format}{\raggedright}
   \makeatother
   \begin{document}
   \section{A section}
   \lipsum
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) and modify `\sectionfont`:

   ```
   \documentclass{ctexart}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usepackage{sectsty}
   \sectionfont{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}
   \begin{document}
   \section{A section}
   \lipsum
   \end{document}
   ```

Both instances above yield as output:

[image]

One would have to follow a similar technique for other sectional units.

Comment: We need not hack into the package. Sorry for the Chinese document only.

Answer (score 6):

One would think that the definition

```
\def\CTEX@section@format{\Large\bfseries}
```

found on line 20 of `ctex-article.def` would the one valid for articles. For mysterious reasons, in the `ctexcap.cfg` file one finds

```
\def\CTEX@section@format{\Large\bfseries\centering}
```

The file states

```
% ctexcap.cfg: default Chinese caption settings
```

I find it confusing, but that's the situation. You can fix it by just restoring the first definition:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\CTEX@section@format{\Large\bfseries}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We need not hack into the package. Sorry for the Chinese document only.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [the document](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ctex) first.

For `ctex` v1.02d and older version:

```
\CTEXsetup[format=\Large\bfseries]{section}
```

For `ctex` v2.0 and later:

```
\ctexset{section/format=\Large\bfseries}
```