# Left Adjustment of Title

Tags: indentation, titlesec, section-titles

I want to adjust the title indentation for all the section and subsection titles as shown in the image. How can I achieve this using the `titlesec` or other similar packages?

This is a minimal version of my current code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

[...]

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=3.5cm,
right=2cm,
top=3.5cm,
bottom=2cm
}

[...]

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Background}
\subsubsection{Machine Reading Comprehension (MRC)}
MRC is a subfield.........

[...]
    

\end{document}
```

**What I want:**
[image]

**What I have:**
[image]

I am using a `documentclass{report}` and my section titles are in the left edge of the paper by default. But I would like to indent them 3.5mm from the left edge of the paper as shown in the above image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to left align the section title in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219749/how-to-left-align-the-section-title-in-latex)

Comment: No. I am using a documentclass{report}, and my section titles are already aligned to the left side of the paper. But I would like to indent them 3.5mm from the left edge of the paper.

Comment: Well would you like to paste an minimal working example? Let us know how you align title left?

Comment: @ Raavan. This is important information that you should have given from the beginning. Maybe you should read first [How to ask a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and provide a MWE.

Comment: @Raavan please see if the answer meets the requirement  -- as amended from the solution given here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25082/customizing-indentation-in-section-and-subsection-headings

Comment: @Roland done, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TEX.SE! I use `titlesec` package to meet this requirement.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=3.5cm,
right=2cm,
top=3.5cm,
bottom=2cm
}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter .}{3.5mm}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{3.5mm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection .}{3.5mm}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{3.5mm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection .}{3.5mm}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{3.5mm}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Background}
    \subsection{Machine Reading}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I got the length value from `texdoc titlesec` sec 9.2 "Standard Classes".

Comment: This worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%1inch=25,4mm
\titlelabel{{\hspace*{1cm}\makebox[1cm][l]{\thetitle}}}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
    \section{foo}
    \hspace*{25.4mm}\lipsum[1]
    \section{bar}
    \subsection{foo bar}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```